# Subclassing NSArrayController causes objects from ManagedObjectContext doesn't show in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nspersistentdocument, nsmanagedobjectmodel

That's very strange. I have a Model with three Entities. Like this:
[image]

In InterfaceBuilder I made NSArrayController connected to MOC via RepresentedObject to ViewController. Everything works, I can add and delete Master objects, select them, I can bind to TableView and edit them. But if I subclass NSArrayControler to MasterController and add just observer:

```
class MastersController: NSArrayController {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selection", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    Swift.print("observing", keyPath ?? "<no path>")
    switch keyPath! {
    case "selection":
        Swift.print("selection Changed")
    default: break

    }
}
```

TableView doesn't see already existing objects, only just added. I can edit them. But when I open the document again newly added objects disappear too. If I will change the class of controller back to NSArrayController I can see them all again.

Any help?

Comment: At least it's good habit to check for key path or context and call super if the check does not succeed.

Comment: Colud You explain? I'm type designer :) Key path of what exactly? Could changing class change context or some key path?

Comment: Probably it's not related to the issue but methods like `observeValue(forKeyPath` are supposed to call super if the affected key path or the context don't match the observer of the current class. If you don't call super the super class does not respond to that method

Comment: Problem was solved by super.awakeFromNib. Thank You!

Comment: Why do you want to subclass `NSArrayController`?

Comment: To add @IBAction addMaster(_ sender:Any) based on selection in another Controller. I don't know how to do it in another way.

Comment: Use an extension.

Comment: May I add @IBOutlet to extension?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure `observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` is used internally by `NSArrayController` and you should call `super.observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:)` to get the expected behaviour...

Comment: It didn't help, but super.awakeFromNib helped! Thank You!

Comment: @Łukasz Create your own answer with your solution and accept it, so others with the same problem may find it. ;)

Comment: Thank You very much! I did it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by calling `super.awakeFromNib()` in overrided `func awakeFromNib()`